# Удвоение в слове "Говоренный"

Tags: прилагательные, причастия

Говореное слово не вернешь обратно.

Стоит ли в приведённом предложении удваивать букву "Н" в слове "говоренный"? Вид — несовершенный, зависимых слов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы да. Словари:
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/780490
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/говорённый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Слова с одной Н не обнаруживается в словарях XX и XXI столетий. Не всегда существуют (используются либо закреплены в словарях) оба варианта. В данном случае даже вариант с НН крайне редкий (Гугл: "Результатов: примерно 96") — но существующий.

Можно предположить, что данное слово устаревшее, так как оно отсутствует в современных толковых словарях.

По аналогии с "заговорё**нн**ый" и "сказа**нн**ое слово" (используется в данной пословице):
[https://orfogrammka.ru/блог/интересное/сказаный-сказанный/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/)

А вообще, если не учитывать существование форм, то в таких случаях выбор за автором: качество либо акцент на действии.

Comment: Да, в этой поговорке - вышедшее из широкого употребления _прилагательное_ (в отличие от Ушаковского причастия, которое для других контекстов). Аналогия же его написания со словом "сказанное" не проходит, поскольку (по вашей ссылке) глагол "сказать" - _совершенного_ вида, а "говорить" - _несовершенного_ (от таковых могут быть образованы отглагольные прилагательные).

Comment: Аналогия в том, что оно взаимозаменяемо. Нет, вышедшее из употребления в принципе.

Comment: Из заменяемости по смыслу не следует орфографичекая аналогия (в качестве примера таковой вы привели другое по смыслу слово, "заговоренный").

Comment: Тут следует: смысл в причастии либо в отглагольном прилагательном и лишь разница в наличии приставки (морфемный фактор). Это лишь аналогия (сходство).

Answer (score 0):

С одной -н- обнаруживается у [Даля](https://megabook.ru/article/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%E2%94%80%20%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%92.%D0%98.%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F).

[Словарь синонимов и антонимов для школьников](https://www.google.ru/books/edition/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%B0/AbwUEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&pg=PA610&printsec=frontcover), с приложениями (Татьяна Гридина, ‎Надежда Коновалова, ‎Ольга Михайлова · 2021):

> Всё мы говорим, да не всё по-говоре**н**ому выходит.

Comment: Раз его нет в словарях XX века, то оно не то что устаревшее, а древнее. Не думаю, что стоит употреблять такие слова.

Comment: Вы бы отредактировали поговорку (в вопросе - пример из этого жанра): "Кушай варёное да слушай говорёное"? Ведь в русском удвоенная "н" произносится (здесь это разрушило бы звучание).

Comment: В плане звучания — да, но рифма не повод отступать от правил: стоит ориентироваться на существование слова. Не звучит у меня одно Н, не зря же оно осталось в XIX веке.

Comment: В этой пословице (по Гуглу) используется "сказа**нн**ое слово".

Comment: По гугл-книгам эта поговорка находится без искажений: Коммуникативные аспекты языка и культуры, 2008 https://www.google.ru/books/edition/Kommunikativnye_aspekty_i%CD%A1azyka_i_kul%CA%B9/dQEqAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5

Comment: Не вижу пословицу по ссылке.

Comment: Я думал, вы о приведенной мной поговорке. Если важно словосочетание "говореное слово", то оно есть и в более известной пословице "Говореное слово серебро..."

Comment: Я о пословице из вопроса ("сказанное слово" находит). А эта (ваша) — XVIII века.